# match is not a function - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to test my object for a pattern and output if it does but the consolel gives me an error saying match is not a function whereas [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) says its a javascript function

```
var templateRegex = '/\${([\S\s]*?)\}/g';



    var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
            return $(el).find("*").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
                return this.nodeType == 3 ;
            });
        };

        var textNodes = getTextNodesIn('#'+currentId);

        console.log(textNodes.length);
        for(var i=0; i<textNodes.length; i++) {
            console.log(textNodes[i]);
            if(textNodes[i].match(templateRegex)) {
                console.log(textNodes[i]);
            }
        }
```

Help please?

Comment: What do your `console.log`s print?

Comment: There's something called [**new RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for that! -> `var templateRegex = new RegExp("/\${([\S\s]*?)\}/", "g");`

Comment: Is `textNodes` an array of strings? What does `getTextNodesIn` do?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to match a RegExp against a node; `match` is a string method, not an HTMLElement method.

Comment: @Graham - there you go, that's the problem right there, +1. Should be posted as an answer! It even looks like it's a jQuery object, as it's returned in the filter() function.

Comment: @Graham whats the solution i been wrapping my head around for a while cant see a way why it should not work

Comment: match() only works on strings, actual text, you are returning a jQuery array-like object with DOM elements.

Comment: @adeneo i got it . but then how do i do it with dom elements ?

Comment: As stated by Graham below, you can use `textNode.eq(i).text().match(templateRegex)`

Comment: @adeneo i will give it a try thanks for your prompt responses +1

Comment: @adeneo no js method works on the Dom element object..;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to match a RegExp against a node; match is a string method, not an HTMLElement method.

Note that jQuery's `contents()` method returns text nodes, not strings. You probably want to use `text()` or `html()` instead (just checking jQuery's API ref at a glance, I'm not a jQuery expert).